# Can MVVM architecture be used in designing web applications?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, wpf, mvvm, asp.net-mvc-4

One of the client for whom I had worked has a MVVM architecture for web application.I dont know why they incorporated instead of MVC. is this a feasible idea because as far as I have gone through all MVVM tutorials if they are concerned with XAML or WPF ,they are going for MVVM.Can anybody explain in detail ?.

Comment: It already is.  Have a look at Angular 2 and Aurelia.

Answer (score 3):

According to [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/338694/mvvm-is-it-better-suited-for-web-applications-or-guis?rq=1) there are people other than your client using `MVVM` for web applications so at least we know he/she/they is/are not crazy :D.

Jokes aside in `MVVM` you have:

1. A `Model` which is either a domain model and represents state content or data content (as in this grid is filled with data from that table)
2. A `View` which is the same as in `MVC` and `MVP` patterns and deals with how the data is presented to the user.
3. A `View Model` which access the data and expose it properties and keeps the business logic away from the view (instead of programming events directly in the Code Behind we now have Commands in our View Model)
4. Finally there's a `binder` component which mediates between the view and the view model and (hence the "Data Binding" thingy).

That translates into the`WPF` world as:

1. `EF` or your favorite `ORM`.
2. `XAML`.
3. Your `ViewModel` class with a lot of support from it's friends in `System.ComponentModel` and `System.Windows.Data`.
4. `XAML` again (everytime you type `{Binding Whatever}`) and a bunch of classes from `System.Windows.Controls` and such that deal with all the "Data Binding".

How do we go from here to the web? The good people of Microsoft [explained](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798384.aspx) that `MVVM` and `MVP` are not that different but

> whereas the MVP pattern is best suited to traditional server-rendered
>   Web pages and the request/response paradigm, the MVVM pattern is
>   optimized for stateful rich client applications where client-side
>   business logic and application state is maintained through user or
>   service interactions

So does that means `MVVM` is meant to deal with an **stateful** environment while others like `MVP` are meant for **stateless**?. Back in the day I assume that something alike was said by some hard core Smalltalkers when someone suggested to use `MVC` for developing web applications and we all know how that argument ended.

As far as I'm aware there are some web related frameworks already using `MVVM` (actually they're using Model View Binder but you know, potato, potato) like `Knockout.js`, also many `AngularJS` users are knowingly or not doing some kind of `MVMM` too.